# Which design is the best for this scenario?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, abstract-class

Can anyone tell me which design is the best for this scenario?

I have classes called `BasicAccount`, `SavingAccount` and `CurrentAccount`.

`SavingAccount` and `CurrentAccount` should have all the features of `BasicAccount`. Later it might be the case that we may introduce a new Account called `AdvanceAccount`, it should have all the features of `CurrentAccount` and `SavingAccount`. How should I design the structure?

My answer:

- lets keep `BasicAccount` as abstract, `SavingAccount` is also abstract, and implements `BasicAccount`
- Create one interface `ICurrentAccount` and currentaccount implements `BasicAccount` and `ICurrentAccount`,
- If we have `AdvanceAccount` then implement it with `SavingAccount` and  `ICurrentAccount`.

Is there any better way? This was asked to me in an interview and the interviewer was not satisfied with my answer I guess.

Comment: if SavingsAccount is abstract, how can anyone open a SavingsAccount ?

Comment: Why would SavingAccount be abstract?  And why treat the two branches differently?

Comment: I think its straightforward to use interface implementation here as per the accounts hierarchy. That way sub-type accounts can be sure to have all main-type account functionality in addition to their own. Also that helps to implement those mandatory functionalities in their own ways.

Comment: Terminology: a class *implements* an interface, but *inherits / extends / derives from* a base class.

Comment: Is `Advanced Account` supposed to work with both `Saving Account` and the `Current Account` in the same time or just to have access to information for one of these two when it's needed ?

Comment: I would ask the interviewer to clarify why he wasn't satisfied with your answer. That's a learning opportunity for both. Don't expect a full training on the subject, but something along the lines of `i was expecting <some pattern> in your answer` can go a long way towards understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
abstract class BasicAccount {}

interface ISavingAccount {}
interface ICurrentAccount {}

class SavingAccount : BasicAccount, ISavingAccount {}  
class CurrentAccount : BasicAccount, ICurrentAccount {}  
class AdvanceAccount : BasicAccount, ISavingAccount, ICurrentAccount {}
```

If `SavingAccount` and `CurrentAccount` have a lot of functionality, you can use aggregation in `AdvanceAccount` implementation:

```
class AdvanceAccount : BasicAccount, ISavingAccount, ICurrentAccount 
{
    private readonly SavingAccount savingAccount;
    private readonly CurrentAccount currentAccount;

    public AdvanceAccount()
    {
        savingAccount = new SavingAccount(...);
        currentAccount = new CurrentAccount(...);
    }

    // redirect ISavingAccount and ICurrentAccount implemetation
    // to savingAccount and currentAccount respectively
}
```

**UPD**.
Note, that direct instantiation of `SavingAccount` and `CurrentAccount` in `AdvanceAccount` is just a sample. IRL you probably will use IoC container.

Comment: Instead of three level Interface Implementation.....Aggregation is a good and understandable technique....

Comment: Good answer. It's exactly what i thought too (you were quicker to answer though). But i'd use IoC here as i do not like the idea of instantiating `SavingAccount` and `CurrentAccount` classes in constructor the way it was done in this answer...

Comment: @Fabjan: yes, this is definitely a work for IoC. But this is just a sample.

Comment: For Aggregation method Interface implementation "class AdvanceAccount :  BasicAccount, ISavingAccount, ICurrentAccount " is required?. As your creating the private variables in "AdvanceAccount".

Comment: @andy: if some method works with `ISavingsAccount` only, I need inherit this interface in `AdvanceAccount` to be able to pass it to that method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic diamond problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance

There are various ways to look at it. In in end it really depends on your other aspects of the design.

- One of the ways is create inheritance using behaviour
- Other is to create inheritance using data (derived classes primarily share data)

If you can split the behaviours using services, you should be able to add / remove behaviours into any new classes that you want, they should only be derived from the base account, if they can be derived from other sub classes then that's a bonus...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that decorator pattern is more applicable here than traditional inheritance.

```
public interface IBasicAccount { }
public interface ISavingAccount { }
public interface ICurrentAccount { }
public interface IAdvanceAccount { }

public class BasicAccount : IBasicAccount { }

public class SavingAccount : ISavingAccount
{
    // methods may use basic account internally to delegate some function calls
    private readonly IBasicAccount _basicAccount;

    public SavingAccount(IBasicAccount basicAccount)
    {
        _basicAccount = basicAccount;
    }
}

public class CurrentAccount : ICurrentAccount
{
    private readonly IBasicAccount _basicAccount;

    public CurrentAccount(IBasicAccount basicAccount)
    {
        _basicAccount = basicAccount;
    }
}

public class AdvanceAccount : IAdvanceAccount
{
    private readonly ISavingAccount _savingAccount;
    private readonly ICurrentAccount _currentAccount;

    public AdvanceAccount(ISavingAccount savingAccount, ICurrentAccount currentAccount)
    {
        _savingAccount = savingAccount;
        _currentAccount = currentAccount;
    }
}
```

You can delegate your calls to internal IBasicAccount, ISavingAccount and ICurrentAccount implementations where it's required.
Also, you can make `ISavingAccount` and `ICurrentAccount` inherit from `IBasicAccount`, if that's required by your business model.

Comment: How would you delegate a `Withdraw(decimal amount)` method?

Comment: This isn't so much a `Decorator` as it is a `Composite`

Comment: True, it will be a decorator if all accounts implement one common base interface.

Comment: You'd delegate the call with something along the lines of `void Withdraw(decimal amount) { _basicAccount.Withdraw(amount); }`

Comment: Either interfaces should inherit from `IBasicAccount`, or `SavingAccount` and others should implement `IBasicAccount` too. Otherwise you'll need to duplicate `IBasicAccount` methods, and there's no any base type in hierarchy (e.g., you can't put all these accounts into some account collection).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what already been said, and provided that we do not require both `SavingAccount` and `CurrentAccount` instances at the same time we can use something like this :

```
abstract class BasicAccount
{
   // .. some implementation here
}

class SavingAccount : BasicAccount { }

class CurrentAccount : BasicAccount { }

class AdvancedAccount<T> where T : BasicAccount
{
    private readonly T _instance;

    public T AccountToWorkWith { get { return _instance; } }

    public AdvancedAccount(BasicAccount instance)
    {
        this._instance = instance as T;
    }
}
```